# How to combine two worksheets (with different data between them) into one Pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have one sheet that I manually enter quality scores on that looks like this

`|Agent Name|Month|Quarter|Year|Quality Form|Score|`

and another sheet that has production data (call times and goals)

`|Agent Name|Month|Quarter|Year|Talk Time|# Calls|Call Goal|`

I am trying to make a Pivot table (with slicers) that provides data that looks like this (the slicers would be for the month, quarter, year, or employee name)

`|Agent Name|Score|Call Goal|`

Tried messing with slicers. Tried consolidating tables. Tried using the data model. Tried using relationships (it kept telling me it needed unique values)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Power Pivot add-in to load both your tables into the Data Model (**Excel** -> tab "**Power Pivot**" -> button "**Add to Data Model**"), define the relationship between them (**Power Pivot for Excel** -> tab "**Design**" -> button "**Create Relationship**") and after that create your desired PivotTable in a new sheet (**Power Pivot for Excel** -> tab "**Home**" -> button "**PivotTable**").

Don't see a tab "Power Pivot"? Enable the add-in:

- From the File menu, select Options, and then Add-Ins.
- In the "Manage" box, select COM Add-ins, and then click Go....
- Check the box next to Microsoft Office PowerPivot for Excel 2013, and then click OK.

As you mentioned already, you do need at least one of the tables to contain merely unique keys. Don't have it? Create one by combining multiple columns as a new column. Assuming each agent only occurs as a record in your tables once per month/year, you could use Power Pivot to concatenate a unique key into a new column with a formula like:

**=Table1[Agent Name]&Table1[Month]&Table1[Year]**

Do the same in Table 2:

**=Table2[Agent Name]&Table2[Month]&Table2[Year]**

Now, you can create a relationship between those 2 newly created columns and pivot as much as you want in Excel. Let us know how it works out!